# How to insert a tag in another mutiple times within a pattern? - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have this kind of strings (they are dynamic) which contain LaTeX (I'm using MathJax to read it) fetched from firebase:

```
const string = "Some text \\(x+2\\) some text \\(3t+t\\) some text";
```

How can I convert that string to this?:

```
<Text>Some text <MathJax>x+2</MathJax> some text <MathJax>3t+t</MathJax> some text</Text>
```

I have tried processing the string but it end up still being a string:

```
const string = "Some text \\(x+2\\) some text \\(3t+t\\) some text";

const convertedString = string.replace(/\\\(.*?\\\)/g, match => `<MathJax>${match.slice(2, -2)}</MathJax>`);

const finalString = <Text>{convertedString}</Text>

return finalString; 
//Output (brackets are for representing inner content is a string): 
//<Text>{"Some text <MathJax>x+2</MathJax> some text <MathJax>3t+t</MathJax> some text"}</Text>
```

Comment: You can parse the text yourself by splitting the string and mapping the pieces. It's not a tiny amount of code but looks doable for your sample